# Rails way to pass data from 'for' to modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to pass a variable being defined in an 'for' loop down to a modal button. Currently I have the `modal block` being rendered in the for as a quick win but I find it redundant to be making the entire `modal block` in the DOM for nothing.

```
<h3>User</h3>
<p>Name: <%= @user.name if @user.name %></p>
<p>Email: <%= @user.email if @user.email %></p>
<% @user.authentications.each do |i| %>
    <%= i.provider.titleize %><br>
    <%= i.created_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %><br>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg modal-btn-swap" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data=<%= i.id %>>Delete Auth</button>


<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Remove authorization</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <%= button_to 'Delete Auth', deauth_url(i.id) %>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<% end %>
```

The concept is to just get a modal popup to give legal information prior to completing the transaction.
I'm thinking I'll need ot use jQuery to swap the href for the link when I click the 1st `Delete Auth` button.

Input?

Comment: what data you need in modal popup

Comment: @TusharPal Hello, it's the `        <%= button_to 'Delete Auth', deauth_url(i.id) %>` id within the button it creates.

Answer (score 0):

If you create the modal once, you will have to write some javascript in the button click handler to populate the modal's attributes with the data you want each time you click, rather than hard coding it into each copy of the modal as you are doing now.

The ruby code would generate the modal -- you would have to leave the button_to('Delete Auth') without a target. Then you can copy the values from the data attribute to the modal when you click the button.